# How to use extra 256 gb space in Ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I need help to use my extra 256 GB of space in ubuntu. I am new to Linux and don't know how to use this extra space because it is not allowing me to write anything on it (means to create a folder or copy something there). For your reference, I attached the image of my current storage space, please look at the attached image.

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed the permissions for `/media/sanaullah/extra`? If they’re `root:root` then you’ll want to update it for your account and group.

Comment: I am new to Linux and do not have any idea what I have to do with this issue. If you can provide me some commands which can help me

Comment: More info on mounting & sharing. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk You can make name of your mount anything that makes sense to you, if you do not want to call it /mnt/data. You can link folders into /home if desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a Dell. If that is Gparted cli, open in GUI mode. Your 256 GB is on a separate drive. The partition named `nvmeon1` is on an M2 disk. That name is reserved for m2 drives on Dell. You can check it via the dropdown menu in GUI. I am not sure if you need to mount or not, but I would assume so.

Comment: Your PC has 2 internal drives. One is a classic SSD and the other M2. Seems like a trend among mid-grade models. My Dell G5 5590 has the same setup. I am running Ubuntu on a 1 T internal partition.. The SSD.